# Booting Ubuntu from USB - don't see where I can choose USB over my hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am running Windows 7 on my laptop but want to get Ubuntu OS. I put the ISO file on a USB stick and made it 'bootable' or whatever. When I restart my computer and hit F12 to go to the boot menu, there is no option to download Ubuntu from my USB stick. I tried going into the BIOS menu and then tried running the CD/DVD option and neither of those worked. Am I missing something? The USB stick should be bootable and ready to go with the Ubuntu 12 ISO

Comment: In order for the USB stick to become bootable you need to write the iso image using a special program like UNetBootin. Putting the iso on the USB stick does not make it automatically bootable.

Answer (score 0):

That does not have to do anything with ubuntu itself, that means that your usb stick is not properly attached, or not recognized by bios.

Problem caused by ubuntu could be, that usb is not bootable, and it then automatically switches to boot from hard disk, but it is recognized by boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

To make a bootable flash drive you do not just copy an iso file there. You need to use some program to write image to your usb drive. It can be done many ways. You can use [THIS MANUAL](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) as an example.